# An observable to emit tuple of latest values of N other observables?

Tags: reactive-programming, reactivex

Is there any operation like [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html), but which not waits for entire tuple gather, but emits tuple on each change.

For example if it just emitter `1A` and `B` came on second observable, it immediately emits `1B`, which is "latest" tuple.

At the beginning, this operation should wait until all `N` elements gather.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is usually called `zipLatest`.

Here's an example implementation in Python:

```py
from typing import *
import rx
import rx.operators as ops

def zip_latest(*xss: rx.Observable) -> rx.Observable:
    helper = ZipLatestHelper(len(xss))
    return mux(*xss).pipe(
        ops.map(helper.process),
        ops.filter(lambda x: x is not None),
    )

def mux(*xss: rx.Observable) -> rx.Observable:
    def pair_index(i: int) -> Callable[[Any], Tuple[int, Any]]:
        def inner(x: Any) -> Tuple[int, Any]:
            return i, x
        return inner

    paired = [xs.pipe(ops.map(pair_index(i))) for i, xs in enumerate(xss)]
    return rx.from_iterable(paired).pipe(ops.merge_all())

class ZipLatestHelper:
    def __init__(self, num_streams):
        self.latest = [None for _ in range(num_streams)]
        self.ready = set()

    def process(self, pair: Tuple[int, Any]) -> Optional[Tuple[Any, ...]]:
        i, x = pair
        self.latest[i] = x
        self.ready.add(i)
        return (
            tuple(self.latest) if len(self.ready) == len(self.latest) else None
        )
```

And usage:

```py
from time import sleep

zipped = zip_latest(
    rx.interval(0.5).pipe(ops.map(lambda i: f"A{i}")),
    rx.interval(0.3).pipe(ops.map(lambda i: f"B{i}")),
)
zipped.subscribe(print)
sleep(10)
```

With output:

```py
('A0', 'B0')
('A0', 'B1')
('A0', 'B2')
('A1', 'B2')
('A1', 'B3')
('A2', 'B3')
('A2', 'B4')
('A2', 'B5')
```

Caveats:

- May not be thread-safe.
- What should one do if a stream receives `OnCompleted`? Should the zipped stream continue emitting items, or should it issue an `OnCompleted`?
- What should one do if a stream receives `OnError`?